# Dwolla checkout doesn't ask for funding source

Tags: dwolla

I'm trying to setup a form that posts to https://www.dwolla.com/payment/pay to make a payment. I've already created a Dwolla account for the user at this point using the REST API, however I'm using this method for payment because the REST API add/verify funding_sources calls don't work yet. So basically, at this point, the user has an account however they don't yet have a funding source.

Upon post of the payment form, it redirects the user to: https://www.dwolla.com/payment/login?returnurl=%2fpayment%2fcheckout%2fsomeid and asks them to login or do a guest checkout. They choose to login with their credentials, and then it has them enter their pin and Checkout. After that it returns the error: "failure - Insufficient funds exist to complete the transaction."

Obviously there are insufficient funds, the user hasn't added a funding source yet. I would expect it to prompt the user to add a funding source right there as part of the checkout process. Between the API issues and this, I am blocked on using Dwolla as a viable solution for having my users make payments, as I can't just say "Go to dwolla.com and add a funding source", that would be a terrible UX...

Is there some way to configure the payment checkout to prompt the user to add a funding source? I already have set:

```
<input type="hidden" name="allowFundingSources" value="true" />
```

Comment: Offsite Gateway wasn't intended as a way for Dwolla users to verify funding sources. We are aware of the Add/Verify funding sources issue and are working to resolve it.

Comment: Add/Verify banks should now work.